# Having trouble with downloading a page using the requests function - returning the 410 html error code but works in browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I've tried searching for this - can't seem to find the answer!

I'm trying to do a really simple scrape of an entire webpage so that I can look for key words. I'm using the following code:

```
import requests
Website = requests.get('http://www.somfy.com', {'User-Agent':'a'}, headers = {'Accept': '*/*'})
print (Website.text)
print (Website.status_code)
```

When I visit this website in a browser (eg chrome or firefox) it works. When I run the python code I just get the result "Gone" (error code 410).

I'd like to be able to reliably put in a range of website urls, and pull back the raw html to be able to look for key-words.

**Questions**
 1. What have I done wrong, and how should I set this up to have the best chance of success in the future.
 2. Could you point me to any guidance on how to go about working out what is wrong?

Many thanks - and sorry for the beginner questions!

Comment: It's extremely likely that the site is detecting your attempts to automatically access it and blocking the attempt for security reasons. Looking at the site, it also appears to be using ajax or similar to load the page asynchronously. You may need a browser automation tool like Selenium rather than requests

Comment: Hi @G. Anderson, and thank you for the reply! Ignoring the security employed by the website, is a browser automation tool like Selenium able to load everything that a normal browser can load?

Comment: Selenium creates an actual browser that fully loads the page as if a user was visiting the page, even if it's loaded asynchronously. They may still block it if they detect automation, but that's a separate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid User-Agent and you didn't include it in your headers.

I have fixed your code for you - it returns a 200 status code.

```
import requests
Website = requests.get('http://www.somfy.com', headers= {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3835.0 Safari/537.36', 'Accept': '*/*'})
print (Website.text)
print (Website.status_code)
```

Comment: @FromeCoder You're welcomed :) Please accept my answer if it fixes your problem (the green checkmark on the left)